# Docker compose/Swarm: Use network names of compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-network

I work with a compose file which looks like this:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  shinyproxy:
    build: /home/shinyproxy
    deploy: 
      #replicas: 3
    user: root:root
    hostname: shinyproxy
    image: shinyproxy-example
    networks:
      - sp-example-net
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /var/run/docker.sock
        target: /var/run/docker.sock
      - type: bind
        source: /home/shinyproxy/application.yml
        target: /opt/shinyproxy/application.yml  
....

networks:
  sp-example-net:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
```

This shinyproxy application uses the following .yml file

```
proxy:
  port: 5000
  template-path: /opt/shinyproxy/templates/2col
  authentication: keycloak
  admin-groups: admins
  users:
  - name: jack
    password: password
    groups: admins
  - name: jeff
    password: password
  container-backend: docker-swarm
  docker:
      internal-networking: true
      container-network: sp-example-net
  specs:
  - id: 01_hello
    display-name: Hello Application
    description: Application which demonstrates the basics of a Shiny app
    container-cmd: ["R", "-e", "shinyproxy::run_01_hello()"]
    container-image: openanalytics/shinyproxy-demo
    container-network: "${proxy.docker.container-network}"
    access-groups: test
  - id: euler
    display-name: Euler's number
    container-cmd: ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/root/euler')"]
    container-image: euler-docker
    container-network: "${proxy.docker.container-network}"
    access-groups: test
```

To deploy the stack I run the following command:

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml test
```

This results in the following: Creating network `test_sp-example-net`

So indead of `sp-example`_net my network´s name is `test_sp-example_net`

Is there a way to prevent this kind of combination for my network name?

Thank you!

Comment: did you tried using name property, see this : https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#name-1

Comment: yep I did, maybe it´s not a bug, saw it in a tutorial too...

Comment: if it is not working. then you can also fix the project name by default it is the directory name in which compose file is placed.